# Given a binary tree, \$T\$ whose nodes have positive values, find the value of the maximal path

Tags: python, recursion, tree, depth-first-search

## Problem

Problem is **Maximum sum path** from https://firecode.io

Given a binary tree, \$T\$, whose nodes have positive values find the value of a maximal path. A path is a simple path from a node to another node. The value of a path \$P\$ is

$$val(P) = \sum\limits_{u \in P} val(u)$$

that is, the sum of the values of the nodes along \$P\$. A maximal path \$M\$ is one that satisfies:

$$\forall\ \ paths\ \ P,\ \ val(P) \le val(M)$$

## Python solution

```
class BinaryTreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data, left = None, right = None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, root = None):
        self.root = root

    def max_sum_path(self, root):

        _, val_of_max_path = self._val_of_max_path(root)

        return val_of_max_path

    def _val_of_max_path(self, root):
        ''' Returns a tuple:
            ( val of the maximal path
              from a leaf up to root,

              val of the maximal path
              from a node to another
              node in this subtree )
        '''

        # base case
        if not root:
            return (0, 0)

        # recursive case

        ( val_of_max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_left_child,
          val_of_max_path_in_left_subtree ) = (

              self._val_of_max_path(root.left) )

        ( val_of_max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_right_child,
          val_of_max_path_in_right_subtree ) = (

              self._val_of_max_path(root.right) )

        val_of_max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_root = root.data + max(

            val_of_max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_left_child,
            val_of_max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_right_child )

        val_of_max_path_that_has_a_turning_point_at_root = (

            val_of_max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_left_child +
            root.data +
            val_of_max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_right_child )

        val_of_max_path_in_this_subtree = max(

            val_of_max_path_in_left_subtree,
            val_of_max_path_in_right_subtree,
            val_of_max_path_that_has_a_turning_point_at_root )

        return ( val_of_max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_root,
                 val_of_max_path_in_this_subtree )
```

## Comments

I use very long descriptive variable names. I am not sure if I am overdoing it or not. Do you see a way to shorten them whilst maintaining meaning? I have an upcoming technical interview so I want to make sure I exhibit good style. Also, I will be coding in a shared Google Doc, so I won't have access to syntax highlighting. Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, those names are too long. They contain some redundant information - that's one sign how to tell whether they're *too* long, rather than just long. For example, the "val" prefix does not tell anything new - sure it's a value, what else? Renaming `val_of_max_path_that_has_a_turning_point_at_root` -> `max_path_through_root` leaves all the important information intact.

Comment: @kfx My thought was that `val_of_` helps distinguish between the value of a path and the path itself, but as you said that may be too much info. Would using a shorter vairable name and a comment to explain the meaning be a good compromise?

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of the very long variable names and trying to follow the `PEP8` "79 chars per line" rule really makes the code unreadable.

First of all, you can absolutely *increase the allowed line length from 79 to a more practical 100 or 120*. After all, we are writing code for humans to read, not machines.

Also, I think you can shorten the variable names by removing the "val_of_" part from the beginning. You don't lose any information by doing that.

---

Some other notes:

- you can define tuples without extra parenthesis, e.g. `return 0, 0` instead of `return (0, 0)`
- the docstrings should be put in triple double-quotes. If a docstring is located on multiple lines, it should star with a new line ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings))

---

Here is the code after applying the proposed changes:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def max_sum_path(self, root):
        _, max_path = self._max_path(root)
        return max_path

    def _max_path(self, root):
        """
        Returns a tuple:
            (val of the maximal path from a leaf up to root,
             val of the maximal path from a node to another node in this subtree).
        """

        # base case
        if not root:
            return 0, 0

        # recursive case
        max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_left_child, max_path_in_left_subtree = self._max_path(root.left)
        max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_right_child, max_path_in_right_subtree = self._max_path(root.right)

        max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_root = root.data + max(max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_left_child, 
                                                          max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_right_child)

        max_path_that_has_a_turning_point_at_root = max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_left_child + \
                                                    root.data + \
                                                    max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_right_child
        max_path_in_this_subtree = max(max_path_in_left_subtree, 
                                       max_path_in_right_subtree,
                                       max_path_that_has_a_turning_point_at_root)

        return max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_root, max_path_in_this_subtree
```

Comment: I would suggest using `right_max` and `left_max` for `max_path_in_right_subtree` and `max_path_in_left_subtree`. Can't think of anything good for `max_path_from_a_leaf_up_to_root`, though.

Comment: Maybe `right_max_depth` and `right_max_path`?